# Why QPainterPath::contains() is not thread-safe, despite being const?

Tags: c++, qt, openmp, qpainterpath

While I understand that QT states that only specifically stated classes are thread-safe, I'd like to understand why a "const" marked method - QPainterPath::contains() - breaks when it is being called in a parallel loop without any concurrent write operation:

```cpp
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(-50,-50,100,100);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int x=0; x<100000; ++x)
        if(!path.contains(QPoint(0,0)))
            std::cout << "failed\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The above code randomly outputs "failed", when it shouldn't.

My understanding is that it is changing its internal state somehow, despite the method being "const":
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.cpp.html#_ZNK12QPainterPath8containsERK7QPointF

I need to compare if points are inside the path from multiple threads (in order to speed up processing), but it just does not work with QPainterPath. Even if I create a copy of the object for each thread, QT does Copy On Write and unless I change the derived object (to force it to detach), the result is still the same misbehaviour since it is still using the same shared data. How can I do that in a safe manner without this ugly hack?

Comment: You're right that this is strange, but strictly speaking, a `const` member function isn't *required* to be thread safe. Standard library containers offer that guarantee, and can require it for elements they contain. But the standard doesn't actually require all types to respect this convention. For example, a type may perform some internal caching in a `const` member function for performance reasons, or something similar, in a manner that is not thread safe.

Comment: I guess most (if not all) QT-specific classes are implemented in a copy-on-write manner. Not sure how exactly that influences the concrete example you gave, but you should be aware of it. Also, QT objects are generally not thread safe see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html)

Comment: @alagner QPainterPath::contains() is marked as const, there should be no write operation, so no COW being executed.

Comment: @AdrielJr That is an false assumption. `const` on a member function just means you can call the function on a `const` instance, which implies the visible state of the object shouldn't change. But the internal state can very much change. See `mutable`. In this case, it seems unlikely that COW is happening, but something similar like lazy evaluation may occur.

Comment: @AdrielJr const!=pure (I wish it was present in the language). Const methods can easily execute non-const operation on a member held by pointer or reference, not to mention the `mutable` keyword. Now, one can argue if it’s a good or bad style or a language flaw; bottom line is: const can refer to logical constness only. If it’s also a binary immutability, that’s great but it cannot be enforced on the language level.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks, I was not aware about the ```mutable``` keyword. It just does not make sense for me why did they introduce it to the language. It breaks completely the main semantic meaning of ```const```.

Comment: As for your particular problem: either use mutex (but it’s going to be slow), make the deep copies for each thread (and then notify the main one somehow) or just change data structure.

Comment: @AdrielJr There are several possible and self-consistent definitions you could attribute to "constant" and "immutable" with various levels of granularity and extent. It is not possible to describe them all with a single keyword. I'm just glad we have `const` and `const` member functions at all. The same can't be said for most other languages. I wish the language would let us define additional qualifiers like `const` and `volatile`.

Comment: @ArielJr `mutable` is often considered a code smell unless applied to synchronization variables, say, mutex or condition variable (which can be changed on read); caching is also sometimes applicable here. You might ask about existence of const_cast as well, it has its place, it being abused is a completely different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the first line of code you linked to:

```
if (isEmpty() || !controlPointRect().contains(pt))
```

`controlPointRect()` has the following:

```
if (d->dirtyControlBounds)
    computeControlPointRect();
```

and `computeControlPointRect()` does the following:

```
d->dirtyControlBounds = false;
...
d->controlBounds = QRectF(minx, miny, maxx - minx, maxy - miny);
```

In other words, if you call `controlPointRect()`  in parallel, the following can occur:

- Thread T1 sees `d->dirtyControlBounds` and enters `computeControlPointRect()` which clears it. It gets to work computing the bounds.
- Thread T2 enters `controlPointRect()` and sees that `d->dirtyControlBounds` is false. It checks whether `d->controlBounds` (at this point an empty set of points) contains that specific point. It does not, so it returns false.
- Thread T1 finishes and updates `d->controlBounds`. All threads from now on  are in sync.

The obvious fix for this specific instance is to make sure all dirty bits are cleared before you enter a massively parallel computation, but that might not be possible with all objects.

Comment: Thank you for your very good explanation. I'll make a test calling it once before entering the parallel loop. Despite that, my understanding is that it does not make sense to mark this function as const since they use the dirty design pattern inside. I at leas definitely don't do it in my code.

Comment: Just to let you know that calling controlPointRect() before the parallel environment fixed the issue.

Comment: If the answer helped you, mark it as accepted so other people can find it more easily.

Comment: I just did. Thanks. You may want to upvote the question as well.

Comment: @AdrielJr note that you're relying on the implementation detail now. Imagine sth changes (e.g. is upgraded) and your code might break in various ways for no obvious reason.

Comment: @alagner I'm aware of that. But a 4x speedup in a bottleneck can be convincing. I wish QT would at least provide a detach function for these COW classes.